# Getting NullPointerException when accessing a variable in a Java class

Tags: java, arrays, class, nullpointerexception

I have a problem when setting a variable inside a Java class

Here is my code

This is where I create the instances (IdeaInfo is a class that acts similar to a Struct):

```
IdeaInfo[] IDEAS = new IdeaInfo[100];
String[] TITLES = new String[100];
```

This is the function that will use those instances:

```
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
            // This is adding title to array Ideas and Titles
            if(mode % 3 == 0)   {
                IDEAS[ideas_pos].setTitle(sb.toString());
                TITLES[titles_pos] = sb.toString();
                titles_pos++;
                mode++;
            }
            // This is adding the content to array Ideas
            else if(mode % 3 == 1)  {
                IDEAS[ideas_pos].mContent = sb.toString();
                mode++;
            }
            // This is adding the rating to array Ideas
            else if(mode % 3 == 2)  {
                IDEAS[ideas_pos].mRating = Float.valueOf(sb.toString().trim()).floatValue();
                ideas_pos++;
                mode++;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what I have inside IdeaInfo class:

```
public class IdeaInfo {

    public String mTitle = new String();        // Store the Idea's title
    public String mContent = new String();  // Store the Idea's title
    public float mRating;       // Store the Idea's Rating

    /*
     * Function that set the Idea's title
     */
    public void setTitle(String temp){
      mTitle = temp;
    }
}
```

Apparently, the error occurred inside the try, exactly at `IDEAS[ideas_pos].setTitle(sb.toString());`
The debugger indicated that I am accessing a NullPointerException, this does not really make any sense to me since I already initialize those variables in the class.

By the way, I initialized `ideas_pos` to 0.

Comment: BTW you can replace `new String()` with `""`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in java are initialized "clean", that is, with all elements set to `null` or "zero" (whatever is appropriate for the type of array). When you write

```
IdeaInfo[] IDEAS = new IdeaInfo[100];
```

the JVM will treat it as if you wrote

```
IdeaInfo[] IDEAS = new IdeaInfo[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    IDEAS[i] = null;
}
```

This takes some getting used to if you are coming to Java from a language like C or C++ which has different conventions for initializing arrays.

Answer (score 8):

When you initialize an array, it doesn't mean you've initialized its members.

`IDEAS[x]` is `null`. You'd need to initialize it by:

```
IDEAS[ideas_pos] = new IdeaInfo();
```

Answer (score 3):

I hate to say it but your code should really be re-designed and re-written.

1. For start `sb.append(text + "/n")` is a complete misuse of `StringBuilder`.Use: `sb.append(text).append('\n')`.
2. You never clear or create a new `StringBuilder`, when you'll reach the `Float.valueOf()` part your builder will have a lot of text appended to it.
3. I suggest creating `IdeaInfo` on the `0` switch part and store in the array so you can later reference its values
4. `IdeaInfo` - don't create empty strings (prefer to simply assign `""`).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the items in the list are null.  Try appending:

```
if(IDEAS[ideas_pos] == null) {
    IDEAS[ideas_pos] = new IdeaInfo();
}
```

Same would apply for titles.

Answer (score 0):

Sammm

1. As above, you need to create `IdeaInfo` instances for each array "slot".
2. [Improving the code] Make all the data fields private - provide public accessors (or better yet, methods that act properly on the class - get/set methods are EVIL!). **Encapsulation** is the number 1 golden rule in OO.

   - Ask yourself what happens when you need to change the implementation of `IdeaInfo` in 6 months time and you have lots of other code directly depending upon (changing) the member variable state - you have a maintenance headache!
   - Encapsulating data makes **reasoning** about any class easier - you *know* how the state is changed (via methods only) - the class is easier to get right.
3. Initialise the string data fields to "", not `new String()` which is wasting memory (all empty strings will reference a single String object).